# Email message does not display a mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, email

When my client completes the registration form, I send a confirmation email with the credentials to log in to the use area. The email, when received, does not display one field (agentid) - all other fields show correctly.
Here is a snippet of my code

```
 mysql_query("  INSERT INTO tz_introducers(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt,introid,introducer,officeid,office)
                    VALUES(

                        '".$_POST['username']."',
                        '".md5($pass)."',
                        '".$_POST['email']."',
                        '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                        NOW(),
                        '".$_POST['introid']."',
                        '".$_POST['introducer']."',
                        '".$_POST['officeid']."',
                        '".$_POST['office']."'
            )");

//I now set the field agentid equal to the autoincrement field, id

mysql_query("update tz_introducers set agentid= id where agentid is null");
$agentid= $_POST['agentid'] ;



    if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
    {
        send_mail(  'registration@ISAdistribution.co.uk',
                    $_POST['email'],
                    'Registration Confirmation - Your New Password',
                    "Thanks for Registering.\r\nYour Introducer ID is: {$_POST['introid']}\r\nYour Office ID is: {$_POST['officeid']}\r\nYour Office is: {$_POST['office']}\r\nYour Agent ID is: {$_POST['agentid']}\r\nYour Username is: {$_POST['username']}\r\nYour password is: {$pass}\r\n\r\n\r\n");  


        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password!';
    }
    else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
}

if(count($err))
{
    $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
}   

header("Location: intrologin.php");
exit;
```

I can't understand why the agentid field does not show in the subsequent email. It just shows blank

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Agentid is in the POST data? Your open to SQL injections with this code. Also the mysql_ functions are out of date you should update to mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: I believe your `$_POST['agentid']` is still `null` and so it's not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `$_POST['agentid']` is still `null` and so it's not displaying.

Try using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your `UPDATE` statement instead of directly using the `auto_increment ID` column like

```
mysql_query("update tz_introducers set agentid= LAST_INSERT_ID() where agentid is null");
```

**EDIT:**

I have very less knowledge in `PHP`; answered this question solely cause it's `MySQL` related. But from your last comment, it looks like your `$_POST['agentid']` is `NULL` or `undefined` and so the below line setting `$agentid` to null as well even though the `UPDATE` successes.

```
$agentid = $_POST['agentid'];
```

I think you should be using `mysql_insert_id()` to set the `$agentid` like below and then use `$agentid` in your Email.

```
$agentid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: Thanks - I will try this now, but the database does update immediately with the correct agentid

Comment: Hi. I tried this but it still does not display the agentid in the password

Comment: Sorry, I mean the database updates, but the agentid field does not show in the email. Thanks

Comment: Does all other field gets displayed in email? again, you are storing `$agentid= $_POST['agentid'] ;`. So why not use `$agentid` directly in your email?

Comment: Hi. I changed the line in the script to

Comment: Hi

I changed the relevant part of the line in the script to

\r\nYour Agent ID is: $agentid\r\n

But the email comes back like this

Thanks for Registering.
Your Introducer ID is: 1111
Your Office ID is: des001
Your Office is: Desco
Your Agent ID is: 
Your Username is: test17
Your password is: 33a3d7

The agentid is still blank

Comment: Hi. Thanks but it still doesn't display in the email